# what does a "0" at the end of a raw http header mean (header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/0");)

Tags: php, http-headers

The index.php file in the html document root of a web server contains:

```
<?php

header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/0");
exit();

?>

...
```

(see below for full listing but I think nothing gets done b/c the exit())

There is no file or directory in the document root named "0"

Can anyone tell me what it's doing / why it would be used?

When I enter http:/www.sitename.com/ in my browser address bar, the site loads and the address bar displays:

www.sitename.com/0

if I click on a button, a new page loads and the address bar displays something like:

www.sitename.com/0/index.php?toDo=sometext

and it I type in a file name that doesn't exist like this:

www.sitename.com/0/file_not_there.php

it doesn't complain, it just goes too the main page (and leaves www.sitename.com/0/file_not_there.php displaying in the address bar).

Any assistance you can give in helping me understand what's going on is appreciated.

full listing of public_html/index.php:

```
<?php

header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/0");
exit();

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site Name</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><img src="/somedir/images/logo.png" /></p>
  <p class="style1"><strong>Welcome</strong><br />
 </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's just an URL, `http://www.example.com/0` is semantically no different from `http://www.example.com/chicken-tikka-masala`, unless the site hosting it serves different content with it. If it decides to ignore it, well, it might have its reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken - right, but if there is no "0" resource (file or directory) on the server, I should get a 404 error, no? Unless there is some special handling that I don't know about (that's the part I'm trying to learn). If I go to <http://www.example.com/1> I do get a 404 error. Just so I'm clear, I have ssh access to the server and can see that there is no "0" file or directory in http document root.

Comment: Well, any of the webserver's rewrite rules may kick in, script could enforce that it doesn't show anything if the `0` is not there, etc. There a thousands of ways to do this.

Comment: ok - thanks @Wrikken for giving me a starting place - I'm researching the mod_rewrite now, and learning a lot :)